# How to fill nan when length of values does not match length of index?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataframe (4 columns) with length of 628 values. I want to add Date values ranging from 2012-08-23 to 2014-08-23 with **D** as frequency.

I am using the following code for this.

```
df['Date'] = pd.date_range(start='2012-08-23', end='2014-08-23', freq='D')
```

Since the values of this range are 731, it gives (understandably) the following error:

```
ValueError: Length of values (731) does not match length of index (628)
```

Is there a way I can fill nan to the rest of the columns in the tail where length of date and other columns does not match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via  `Series()` and `concat()` method:

```
date=pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='2012-08-23', end='2014-08-23', freq='D'),name='date')
```

Finally:

```
df=pd.concat([date,df],axis=1)
```